# Select domain's last update date

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, update, domains, datetime

I have tables in an Oracle 18c GDB that I integrate to a work order management system.

I create views on the tables to translate the data. For example, I translate domain `codes` to domain `descriptions`.

I do this by joining to a view that extracts the domain values from the GDB system tables:

```
select
    substr(extractvalue(codedvalues.column_value,'CodedValue/Code'),1,255) as code,
    substr(extractvalue(codedvalues.column_value,'CodedValue/Name'),1,255) as description
from
    sde.gdb_items_vw i 
cross join
    xmlsequence(xmltype(definition).extract('/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue')) codedvalues 
where
    i.name = 'ASSET_STATUS'
```

---

**Question:**

In addition to getting the domain's description, I would also like to select the date that the domain was last updated.

However, I don't see any sort of date field in `sde.gdb_items_vw` and I don't think `scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn)` [will work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681857/10936066).

**How can I select a domain's last update date?**

Comment: Creating a view on an XML column is not likely to be adequately performant. If you make this a *materialized* view, then you won't have to pay all that overhead with each query, and can add a virtual column with the timestamp for the last update.

Comment: Self-answering is encouraged. I haven't had Oracle loaded on the last three laptops, so I'm not going to answer this.

Comment: @Vince Regarding the materialized view on SDE.GDB_ITEMS idea: Is it recommended to put such a view in the SDE owner/schema? Or would that get squirrelly come upgrade time?

Comment: I'd use a different schema, just on principle, but I'd also undo any changes, possibly saving any data in a temporary table, before attempting upgrade (no dangling dependencies)